# Weird problem with fstream. Cannot store objects with member variables having a certain value

Tags: c++, fstream, turbo-c++

When I try to store an object with any element having a value of 13 or 26 or 7 and then try to read this file, it simply gives garbage values. This doesn't happen with other values like 1, 64, 78 (random values).

I have used `ofstream` and `ifstream` separately to keep the code simple. I am using an old compiler (Borland C++) but my friends haven't encountered this error.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>

class xyz
{
  public:
    int x;
};

void main()
{
    xyz a;
    a.x = 45; // replace by 45 or 78 it works. Replace by 13, 26 it shows garbage values.

    ofstream of;
    of.open("file.dat", ios::out||ios::binary);
    of.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
    of.close();

    xyz b;

    ifstream sf;
    sf.open("file.dat", ios::in||ios::binary);
    sf.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b));
    sf.close();

    cout<<b.x;
    getch();
}
```

Currently the output will be 45 but if you replace it by 13 or 26, it prints garbage values.

Comment: You really should consider another compiler. I used Borland C++ in the early 1990s, and the compiler has not been updated since then. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads) with MinGW will provide a relatively recent `gcc`, the free VS2017 Community edition will provide a current MS compiler, and there are several other good options. (avoid `#include <conio.h>` and `getch()`, both are old DOS features 100% non-portable to anything else)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin code::blocks with mingw provides a poor IDE with an old compiler. I'd recommend mingw-w64 with basically any IDE except code::blocks

Comment: I always just used MinGW without Code::Blocks, but since the OP was using Borland C++ (which provided the IDE with TurboC++ compiler), I suspected they would want an IDE as well. I've tried Code::Blocks (the Gtk+2 version) and I didn't find the IDE that lacking..., but then again I never tried to use it for any large or serious project. I agree that a decent compiler and a good text editor is all that is needed. (I like Vim for text based (emacs is fine too), and I've always used Kate as the gui editor -- the KDE3 version `:)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sf.open("file.dat", ios::in||ios::binary);
```

`||` does not do what you think it does. Here, you need to use the bitwise or operator, `|`, and not `||` which is a logical operator.

As a result, your files actually get opened in text mode, instead of binary mode as you intended, because of this mistake.

Your code writes binary octets, 13 and 26, to the file and reads it back. Octets 13, and 26 have special meaning in text files on Microsoft Windows, due to its historical legacy. Your code also fails to check the return value from `read()` and/or the input stream's status, which would've allowed you to detect this error.

Comment: Well Spotted! ++

Comment: About the "13, and 26 have special meaning in text files on Microsoft Windows": 13 is carriage return and 26 is EndOfFile.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your code contains problems, most notably that you're trying to do a bitwise OR with `||` (logical/boolean OR) instead of `|` (bitwise OR) which use to add flags together like you are.

Other things to note (although I'm unsure they are the direct source of the problem) :
 - You forgot to use `std::` when calling standard elements
 - main always needs to return `int`

Type for next time, enable more compiler flags to help find problems in your code.
I don't know turbo-c++ but in g++ you can add `-Wall -Wextra` to get more warnings.
And there are plenty more to enable as well!

Here's your code with the few changes I mentionned

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class xyz
{
public:
  int x;
};

int
main()
{

  xyz a;
  a.x = 45;

  std::ofstream of;
  of.open("file.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  of.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
  of.close();

  xyz b;

  std::ifstream sf;
  sf.open("file.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  sf.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b));
  sf.close();

  std::cout << b.x;
}
```

As a note, if you don't have access to a "recent" compiler (I'm assuming you're stuck on a version) there are several compilers online that allow you to compile code :
 - https://wandbox.org
 - https://gcc.godbolt.org/
 - etc

Answer (score 1):

Your coding isn't actually right here is explanation based on your code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ios>
using namespace std;
struct xyz{
    int x;
};
int main(){

    xyz a, b;
    a.x=134;

    fstream of;
    of.open("file.dat"s, ios::out|ios::binary); // bitwise or
    of.write((const char*)&a, sizeof(a));
    of.close();


    ifstream sf;
    sf.open("file.dat"s, ios::in|ios::binary);
    sf.read((char*)&b, sizeof(b));
    sf.close();

    cout<<b.x<<endl;
    return 0;


};
```